# Rest Assured: Using Request Spec Builder for SOAP request gives Connection timeout error

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, rspec, rest-assured

I have been using Rest Assured for webservices. I am a little new to use SOAP with it.

I created my request using Request Spec builder like this:

```
    RestAssured.config().getSSLConfig().allowAllHostnames();
    RequestSpecBuilder builder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
    builder.setBody(getRequestBody());
    builder.setContentType(getContentType());
    builder.setRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
    builder.addHeaders(getHeaders());
    RequestSpecification specification = builder.build();        
    this.response =given().spec(specification).when().post(getEndPointUrl());
```

But when I run test using it, the Connection timed out error is thrown.

Strange thing is that it works correctly with Rest Request.

For Soap when I run my request using the below syntax: it works fine and I get the response.

```
this.response = given().request()
            .headers(getHeaders())
            .contentType(getContentType())
            .body(getRequestBody())
            .when()
            .post(getEndPointUrl());
```

Can some one help me understanding why it doesnt work with Request Spec Builder and time out.

The Error that I get using Request Spec builder with Soap is pasted below:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at  java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1807)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.post(HTTPBuilder.java:341)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$post$2.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1105)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:31)
at com.jayway.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:49)
at com.jayway.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeFilterChain(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:994)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1452)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1210)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:154)
at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at Helpers.RequestInjection.setResponsePostRequest(RequestInjection.java:69)
at com.orange.webservices.DictServiceTest.happyCase(DictServiceTest.java:28)
```

Answer (score 1):

REST-Assured library, as the name implicitly suggests, only support REST services, not SOAP.

If you want REST and SOAP services to be supported by single framework use [Citrus Framework](http://www.citrusframework.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will certainly look into this framework. But in my case i am able to use the Rest - Assured library pretty well, with the only constraint of using it with Request Spec builder.

Comment: @Atishay, post your query about RequestSpecBuilder in a new question, hopefully SO community will solve the issue.                                                If the answer solved the problem of current question, pls mark it as answer.

Comment: Hi, The question which i have posted is the exact issue i am facing. Your answer is useful for me but my issue still remains intact.

Comment: Confused, as you said in question, REST request is working. Also methods `getRequestBody()`, `getContentType()` and `getHeaders()` dont give much information in the question. Usually connection timeout error comes when the REST base url is incorrect or you dont have access to the server like when it is down

Comment: They are just the getters for which I am setting values from test. Headers inst that important for my requests: content type is - application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; and request body is the xml body

Comment: content type is - application/soap+xml; is for SOAP service and REST-assured dont support SOAP.  if you are passing xml alone, then use "application/xml" conent type

Answer (score 0):

I had run into the same problem and spent quite some time trying to figure out what's the catch.

Turns out, rest-assured automatically appends port 8080 when using RequestSpecBuilder (if not specified). Solved by explicitly specifying port.